# Is it possible to build Adobe AIR native extension with .NET C#?

Tags: air, adobe, air-native-extension

As the question implies, is there any tutorial or article about using .NET C# to build a native extension for Adobe AIR ?

Is it a must to use C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're limited to using C for iOS ANEs or Java for Android ANEs as the Flash Runtime Environment provides an SDK only for those languages. You can, in practice, write your native extension in any language that can properly interface with the SDK language (e.g. Objective-C or C++ on the iPhone, for example).